# function or stored procedure for bulk insert in table by sets

Tags: stored-procedures, teradata

how can i convert the following to teradata stored procedure or some function :
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #temp_set1)
BEGIN

/*group of statemnts :delete insert etc

like */
 INSERT INTO #temp_set
                    SELECT TOP 200 * FROM #temp_set1;
                  INSERT INTO Activepull 
                    as select * from #temp_set1
                and this should occur for each set of 200 untill all inserts

end;

There are more than 60000 rows in #temp_set1 so want to insert by sets.
Thanks.

Comment: Does #temp_set have an identity column?

Comment: @Cheruvian No there is no identity column

Comment: Why do you want to process 60000 rows in 300 sets of 200 rows each? Can you tell what this is actually used for?

Comment: I'm with @dnoeth. Why?

Comment: There are large number of select statements in that needs to be  processed in each loop.The select statements are join of different tables and #temp_set

Answer (score 0):

Written on my phone, but I would use the `over` expression.  It creates a kind of pseudo Identity column that you can then use to paginate. And you can even choose the order based on an order by clause.

```
Declare @IntervalSize int = 100
Declare @BeginSet int = 0,
        @EndSet int = @IntervalSize
While @Counter < (Select Max(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY someColumn desc) From #temp_set1)
Begin
    Insert Into #temp_set 
    Select *, Row_Number() Over (Order By someColumn desc) As MyIdentity
    Where  MyIdentity Between @BeginSet And @EndSet

    Select @BeginSet = @BeginSet + @IntervalSize,
           @EndSet = @EndSet + @IntervalSize
End
```